# UnrealBuildTool Exception: ERROR : failed to harvest environment variables

Tags: visual-c++, unreal-engine4

I am new to dealing with these ERRORS so I need to know every step between getting this error while trying to open a project in unreal editor to having it actually open correctly in Windows 10. I had the same error in Windows 8.1 and in every version of UE4 since 4.9. I went back to it recently because I have been working with Maya since I am new to that as well. I use Visual Studio Community 2015. I can open a blueprint in UE4, but not a C++ Project.

An error occurred while trying to generate project files.

Running C:/Program Files (x86)/Epic Games/4.10/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/Corey/Documents/UE4Projects/Puzzle/Puzzle.uproject" -game -rocket -progress -2015
Discovering modules, targets and source code for game...

UnrealBuildTool Exception: ERROR : failed to harvest environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this many times and I can normally solve it by doing a *Clean Solution* inside Visual Studio and then a *Rebuild Solution*.

It used to be caused by an error in the build code, but I believe that was solved around about 4.8.

Comment: What am I cleaning and rebuilding with Visual Studio?

Comment: I tried it after the Windows 10 update and it worked. Is there anything I can look at so that I can fix it if it happens again?

Comment: Using `Build > Clean Solution` and then `Build >  Rebuild Solution` inside Visual Studio normally solves the issue for me.